What difference would the following change make to the readings of the voltmeters?
I asked a couple of days ago the question that you can find in
Would the two voltmeters measure the same value?
I didn't get an answer to that question. However, I want to make a small modification to it. What if I add another U-shaped conductor enclosing the inner one like the following picture depicts:

Would it make a difference to the readings of voltmeters? I would naively say yes because the induced |emf| in the outer loop is gonna be different, equals $BL^{\prime}$v, from that induced in the inner loop, equals $BL$v. However, a deeper look shows that it's not this simple, because, with this new modification, there exist 3 conducting loops.

I assume that the voltmeters are attached to the U-shaped conductors not the moving conductor?

They're attached to the moving conductor moving with it and held in a plane perpendicular to the the plane of its motion.
